# C# - customizing image name converted to string

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have a method that copies selected image from an `OpenFileDialog` to a defined location, and I want to check if an image with the same name exists, and if so to change the name on the fly.

Here is my method:

```
 public void SaveImage(IList<AppConfig> AppConfigs, string ImageNameFilter)
        {
            string imgPath = AppConfigs[0].ConfigValue.ToString();
            Int32 i = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(selectedFileName);

            while (File.Exists(imgPath + "\\" + ImageNameFilter + selectedFileName))
            {
                sb.Insert(i, 0);
                i++;
                //ImageNameFilter += (i++).ToString();
            }
            File.Copy(selectedFile, imgPath + "\\" + ImageNameFilter + selectedFileName);
        }
```

`ImageNameFilter` is a custom filter that is added at the beginning of each image and the users need this prefix to be able to recognize what the image is used for, only by seeing the prefix. `selectedFileName` is the name of the image taken with `SafeFileName`, which means it looks like this - `imageName.jpeg`.

There are several problems that I have with this code. Firstly, I wanted to change the name like this - `imageName1.jpeg, imageName2.jpeg, imageName3.jpeg...imageName14.jpeg..`, but if I'm using `selectedFileName` with the `+=` everything is added, even after the `.jpeg`, which is not what I want. The only solution that I can think of is to use `regex`, but I really want to find another way.

Also, incrementing `i++` and adding it with `+=` leads to unwanted result which is :
`imageName1.jpeg, imageName12.jpeg, imageName123.jpeg...imageName1234567.jpeg`.

So, how can I get the result I want and the compromise I see here is to add underscore `_` right after the `ImageNameFilter` and then add `i` at the beginning of `selectedFileName` rather in the end as it is by default. But adding something to the beginning of the string is also something I don't know how to do. As you may see I tried `StringBuiledr` + `Insert`, but I don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to separate the base file name from the extension (use the helpful methods on [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to do this) before starting the loop, and then keep producing filenames. Each candidate will *not* be produced based on the last one (it's just based on fixed information and the current iteration count), so you don't need to involve a `StringBuilder` at all.

Here's one neat way to do it in two steps. First, set up the bookkeeping:

```
var canonicalFileName = ImageNameFilter + selectedFileName;
var baseFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(canonicalFileName);
var extension = Path.GetExtension(canonicalFileName);
```

Then do the loop -- here I 'm using LINQ instead of a loop statement because I can, but there's no essential difference from a stock `while` loop:

```
var targetFileName = Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue - 1)
    .Select(i => Path.Combine(imgPath, baseFileName + i + extension))
    .First(file => !File.Exists(file));

File.Copy(selectedFile, targetFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, above my current level but gonna use it.

Comment: @Leron: It's not that involved, although it sure does look so if you are not comfortable with LINQ. It starts from a sequence of integers, converts each one to a filename and picks the first one for which the `!File.Exists()` condition is true (as written, it will throw an exception if it tries all ~2 billion candidates and all of them are in use). The important thing is that all of this is calculated lazily, so it only does as much work as it needs to find an unused filename (vs. making a list of 2 billion candidates up front and then trying each one).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` or `String.TrimEnd('.')` to get the FileName without extension. You can use `FileInfo` to get the extension as well.